# External jQuery script unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to `jQuery` and I am trying to change a `CSS` property (colour) using it. When the `jQuery` script is embedded within the `HTML`, the `CSS` property changes successfully. While the same does not work when the `jQuery` is loaded via the external file as shown below.

Here is my test case which does not work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/colourChange.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h2 id="heading">HTML</h2>

<p><span class="keyword">HTML</span> is a markup language for describing web documents (web pages). <span class="keyword">HTML</span> stands for Hyper Text Markup Language.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The `colourChange.js` is as follows:

```
$("#heading").hover(function(){
$(".keyword").css("color", "blue");
});
```

I am loading the `jquery.min.js` before calling the `colourChange.js`, nevertheless, it doesn't work. Any idea what might be going on wrong here?

Comment: Use $(function(){
$(".heading").hover(function(){
$(".keyword").css("color", "blue");
});
})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that the elements are fully loaded before executing your code. Wrap it in a document ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#heading").hover(function(){
      $(".keyword").css("color", "blue");
   });
});
```

Also heading is an id so it needs to use a "#" symbol in the selector and not a "." (this is used for class).

Answer (score 1):

Since `heading` is a css `id` your code should like this:

```
$("#heading").hover(function(){
$(".keyword").css("color", "blue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your code inside $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#heading").hover(function(){
    $(".keyword").css("color", "blue");
  });
});
```

since "heading" is an id, change . to #